# Docker fails in Visual Studio 2017, how do i get docker to run in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core-mvc

I have installed Docker and turned on Virtualization in the system bios. 
When I go to build a docker container of my .NET Core proj, it fails with this error:

*"The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running."*

- **ALSO NOTE:**
  The Docker Icon in the Docker System Tray does not appear and I am also getting this error as well: time="2017-04-13T21:23:11-05:00" level=info msg=***"Unable to use system certificate pool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows"***

**Full error here with some JSON filter issue as well:**

Error   MSB4018 The "PrepareForBuild" task failed unexpectedly.
Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.CommandLineClientException: error during connect: Get htp://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.27/containers/json?filters=%7B%22name%22%3A%7B%22dockercompose512535401_webapplication1_%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22status%22%3A%7B%22running%22%3Atrue%7D%7D&limit=1: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running..

For more troubleshooting information, go to http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting ---> Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.CommandLineClientException: error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.27/containers/json?filters=%7B%22name%22%3A%7B%22dockercompose512535401_webapplication1_%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22status%22%3A%7B%22running%22%3Atrue%7D%7D&limit=1: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.DockerClient.d__0.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.DockerClient.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.DockerWorkspace.d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.BuildTasks.DockerBaseTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() docker-compose  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets    153

Comment: I cant even switch on windows containers, it wont let me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10

Answer (score 4):

This looks like you have used Docker Toolbox, Toolbox requires an additional step to work properly. You should try running this:

(assuming the default machine exists)

`docker-machine env default`

At the end of that command there will be a note of a command that you have to run depending on the shell environment. For cmd it will look like @for ... And for powershell it will look like an invoke-expression ...

Make sure you run that command, this is very important! Then test the Docker daemon using this:

`docker info`

As a side note those warning about the keyring are not really important, this is just because you are running on Windows and it will have no negative effect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Another side note, the Docker icon will only be present when using Docker for Windows. I guessed you are utilizing Docker Toolbox by the keyring error you described.

Comment: Im running Win7

Comment: I made some headway in WIn10 box, however, my new error is this:                       $ docker run -ti -v /tmp:/tmp aaa953d3b4ca /bin/bash
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"WebApplication2.dll\": executable file not found in $PATH".

Comment: Could you please post your Dockerfile?

Comment: I found this, and it fixed my issue:

[https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/net-core-v111-docker-container-linux-tutorial-joe-hoeller--1][1]


  [1]: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/net-core-v111-docker-container-linux-tutorial-joe-hoeller--1

Comment: @DeltaOmega if you found the solution, post that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Solution: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/net-core-v111-docker-container-linux-tutorial-joe-hoeller--1

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, removing the edge version of docker and installing the stable version resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using VS2017 and Windows 7, while trying to debug and run applications from VS2017.
The problem seems to be that VS can to access the environmental variables needed by docker.
The solution that worked for me was to execute from a CMD or PS the command `docker-machine env default` and then set these values as environmental values at Windows as shown in the following image

[Windows Add Environmental Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pV3U.png)

Comment: Was that link helpful?